# my videos sites start IDM download automatically htaccess?

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a videos site that's shows IDM download dialogue automatically without pressing the download button or even starting the videos player in the site. as the image shows

[image]

i just enter or refresh the site page and this happens!
any fix?

i did not try anything i know

Comment: Please add some [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will allow us to do better for you.

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing some code that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

adding "preload='none'" to the video class fixed the IDM problem, links problem, and auto browser downloading files problem.
thanks